# Save moveable UILabels distributed around the edges of the screen into ordered array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting, uilabel

In my app (a game), I have a bunch of N (number of players) moveable UILabels distributed around the edges of the screen. The `label.text` is pulled from a `PlayerNamesArray`. One of the Labels should randomly be designated as the first element (which I can already do). What I'm having trouble with is, is there someway in which I can then allocate in clockwise, the text of the next label to be the next element in an updated `PlayerNamesArray` ?  (or I could just make a new array)

[image: Very basic illustration]

For example, if MR was the first element, then the array would be `@[@"MR",@"RE", @"QW", ... @"CD"]`

I'm finding this hard because the labels can be moved anywhere along the edges of the view before the "start" button is pressed (so the order could be anything) and only after that is the position of the labels fixed.

Does anyone have any pointers or ideas as to what I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: I'd check each one positions one you start/set the first randomly, and reorder the array according to their new positions.

Comment: but say I move QW between DP and CD. How can I tell that it is between DP and CD and not between MR and RE

Comment: I posted a answer with more informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do like this:

`mainView` is the view where are added all the players.

Have a `NSMutableArray` of `playerLabels`.

Get the `randomFirstPlayerIndex`.

Keep a reference to that `PlayerLabel` (from the `randomFirstPlayerIndex`).

```
UILabel *firstPlayer = [playerLabels objectAtIndex:randomFirstPlayerIndex];
```

Sort `playerLabels` using `sortUsingComparator:` with a custom comparatorBlock.
In this custom comparatorBlock (you can search over the web how to do a custom sort), get the angle from the the center of the `UILabel` (a `playerLabel`) and the center of the `mainView` and compare.

Get the new index of your `firstPlayer`:

```
NSUInteger firstPlayerIndex = [playerLabel indexOfObject:firstPlayer];
```

Reorder `playerLabels` according to it:
Put each object which index if inferior to `firstPlayerIndex` at the end of `playerLabels`.

This is not tested, but that should do the trick, just giving guidelines of the algorithm.

Comment: thanks. This seems like a brilliant idea, I'll try it tomorrow (it's getting late here)